# Pgfplots does not print one bar

Tags: pgfplots

I have this really simple pgfplot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
                     name &    value \\
                        a &  1412629 \\
                        b &  1382400 \\
                        c &  1650981 \\
                        d &  6078327 \\
                        e & 41930786 \\
            }\datapoints
            \begin{axis}[
                ybar,
                symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e},
                xtick=data,
                xticklabels={A,B,C,D,E},
                ymin=0, ymax=7000000
            ]
                \addplot table[x=name, y=value]{\datapoints};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For some reason, the fifth bar for `e` is simply non-existent. Probably the reason is that it is out of range but I expect it to be cut off instead of not being there at all. If I add another datapoint `f & 0` (along with symbolic coords and label), all six bars are there and `e` is cut off as expected.

Why is `e` not cut off as it is when I add another dummy datapoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason, as you guessed, is that you set the maximum value for your `y` as `7000000`, that's 7 million. But your `e` value is `41930786`, so 41 million, at least. So yes, it's out of range.

If you want to have the current configuration and still have `e` to appear, even though it gets cut, then you can restrict the domain.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
                     name &    value \\
                        a &  1412629 \\
                        b &  1382400 \\
                        c &  1650981 \\
                        d &  6078327 \\
                        e & 41930786 \\
            }\datapoints
            \begin{axis}[
                ybar,
                symbolic x coords={a,b,c,d,e},
                xtick=data,
                xticklabels={A,B,C,D,E},
                ymin=0, ymax=7000000,
                restrict y to domain*=0:7000000
            ]
                \addplot table[x=name, y=value]{\datapoints};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of the `*`? I tried it without it before posting this question and it didn't work. (Sorry for the late response)

Comment: @RamboRamon "The starred versions (like `restrict x to domain*`) will truncate coordinates to [<*min*>,<*max*>], i.e. they assign the value <*min*> if the coordinate falls outside of the lower limit and <*max*> if the value falls outside of the upper limit."